# Is it possible to arrange "unrelated" mail messages into a conversation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In my office we share a common mailbox in Outlook in order to keep track of incomming tasks. The nature of our work and organisation generates alot of messages in the inbox that come from different senders but are about the same topic.

We would like to be able to turn these mail messages into a conversation manually. As it is now, we use folders but it becomes rather cluttered.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Have you tried sorting on title rather than date received? You can also sort on both if you want.

Comment: @LPChip Yes, but the problem is that the topics can vary from professional (Issue 4531, Cyber security installation) to outright hillarious ("Some more things abut the cyber stuff..."). It depends highly on the sender.

Comment: I see. In that case it is not possible out of the box. You can only get this result by hacking a system together, which you already did by using folders. Other similar systems would be by adding categories, search filters based on keywords, etc. Maybe the best you can do is have a working folder, and as soon as a topic is done for, move all related messages to an archive folder. You may still have several on-going topics at the same time, but it is more manageable.